# Can I mock a spring boot class method with eventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent) annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to have some initialization in my application. To do so, I use the spring boot annotation `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`. This works well but is (for me) a nightmare when it comes to testing the application.

I always get an error "IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext", when I execute the test.

For better understanding a minimal example:

```
@Component
public class FooImpl implements FooInterface {

    @Autowired
    private MyService anotherServiceIneed;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooImpl.class);

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @Order(1)
    public void doSomethingonApplicationStartup() {
        // do stuff with anotherServiceIneed
    }
}
```

When I test other parts of my application, then, of course, everytime the `doSomethingonApplicationStartup()` is called (Because the ApplicationContext starts).

I tried so many approaches, but always I got the error

For example:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AnotherPartOfTheApplication {
    @MockBean
    FooImpl fooimpl;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() { //do something }

}
```

is not working. Also When I try to mock the `doSomethingonApplicationStartup()` method with `@Before` `@BeforeAll` is not working...

I also tried it with `@MockBean MyService` in the test class, but without success.

Can someone help me, how to test a simple ApplicationReadyEvent annotated method in Spring Boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Please update the question with the full stack trace from the failing test.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is causing this without a fully reproduceable example. However, if all you want is to avoid `FooImpl` from being instantiated during your integration tests then just made this bean not available for test profile.

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class FooImpl implements FooInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But if I want to test the class methods? I just want to avoid the eventListener behavior during tests.

Comment: As Andrew said you need to provide the exception you are getting. Using `@MockBean MyService` locks like right approach. Alternatively, if you want to execute that method you can use the `@Profile` annotation at `MyService` class and have `MyService` instantiated for not test profiles and `MyMockService` doing nothing for your tests. Both `MyService` and `MyMockService` implementing the same interface injected into your interceptor